# Postgresql lock shared table with multiple users

Tags: java, ruby, postgresql, rdbms, postgresql-9.2

So, I'm having a synchronization issue here; Let's explain the situation:

I have a table called `Sendings`, that consists of these columns:

```
id   sending_object_id    type   destinatary
```

The id is the automatic serial id postgresql gives to each table. The sending object_id is a custom identifier, and type and destinatary...don't really matter for this particular question.

This is an example of how the table would look like with data:

```
  id   sending_object_id    type   destinatary
  1          1               1         A7
  2          1               1         B1
  3          2               2         A1
  4          2               2         A2
  5          3               1         B8
  6          4               1         N1
```

The same "`object_id`" can be sent to multiple destinataries, as you can see. Now my synchronization problem comes when two different users, with two different computers, try to insert a new **sending**.

**User A** introduces the new sending information and the DB engine makes a `SelectMax(sending_object_id)` in order to create the new sending_object_id for the registry.

**User B**, at the same time, introduces a new sending, making another `SelectMax(sending_object_id).`

How could I avoid duplicated `sending_object_id`s when inserting new data, at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to lock the table while creating a new sending_object_id, or, if you don't care exactly what the number is create your own [sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) and call [nextval](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) on it.

Comment: What would be the better way to lock a table? And, if I write a sequence, can it be called only for the first insert? (sending_object_id can be repeated for the same series of sendings). Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd just call nextval() in the application at the start of a batch - ignore the result and use currval() for the inserts. That way they all have the same (new) value.

Answer (score 1):

I think need to use [sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) for this. They guaranteed to be unique in any cases.

Comment: Same question than I did to Richard, the nextval for the sequence, can be called only for the first insert of the sending_id set? Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, you can call it only when you need. or even just fiil `nextval('sequence_name')` as default value for column. so first insert will have `default` value and all others has same number (you can get it by using `RETURNING id` clause in insert query).